# vue.js carousel-3d is not showing data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using [Vue Carousel 3D](https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/), and getting dynamic data via an external API call. But whenever I am 
using

```
components: {
    'carousel-3d': Carousel3d.Carousel3d,
    'slide': Carousel3d.Slide
},
```

not able to view the data. I want to get video name and video url in the carousel slider. Please help

[image: Excepted Output]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="blog-post-demo" class="demo">
        <carousel-3d >     
                <slide v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id" v-bind:title="post.title">

                </slide>       
        </carousel-3d>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.8/vue.js"></script>
    <script src='https://rawgit.com/Wlada/vue-carousel-3d/master/dist/vue-carousel-3d.min.js'></script>
    <script>       
        Vue.component('slide', {
            props: ['title'],
            template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>',
        })

        new Vue({
            el: '#blog-post-demo',
            data: {
                posts: []
            },
            created: function () {
                var vm = this
                fetch('http://localhost/WCFCrawler/Service1.svc/GetData')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response.json()
                    })
                    .then(function (data) {
                        vm.posts = data
                    })
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

json format

```
 [
   {
      "src":"http:\/\/localhost\/WCFCrawler\/Videos\/Business - Copy.mp4",
      "title":"Business - Copy"
   },
   {
      "src":"http:\/\/localhost\/WCFCrawler\/Videos\/Business.mp4",
      "title":"Business"
   },
   {
      "src":"http:\/\/localhost\/WCFCrawler\/Videos\/Wildlife.wmv",
      "title":"Wildlife"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `slide` component requires an `index` prop.

```
<slide v-for="(post, i) in posts" v-bind:key="post.id" v-bind:title="post.title" :index="i">
```

As mentioned in the [Vue Carousel 3d](https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/guide/#HTML-Structure) guide:

> Keep in mind that index  property on slide component is required
>   property and you will need to pass it for every slide starting from 0

The index determines the order that the slides appear in. You can set the index manually, but in the example above I've set the array index as the slide index.

I also made a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Robb216/8refhstg/) based on your code.